# Image size via view.xml - possible to set up for category specifically and NOT globally only?

Tags: magento2, product-images, image-resize

For Magento 2 a new feature is the view.xml, which allows me to configure image sizes globally. Image sizes on category, product, and basket pages can all be defined within this xml file by width, height, and the ratio (see a short example below).

[image]

Now my question is: can I configure images here in this view.xml also solely per categories and not globally?

Backround is, I have 95% of my shop product pictures as main images where 600x600px is enough but for some 5% of the products I would need an image size of 900x1200px but really only for those to be sharp on Retina display.

Does anyone have an idea? I´d be grateful for your info.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Each product image in Magento has an id and type properties. They are defined in  node inside view.xml

You just need to find the id and resize it and it will only apply the correct id you changed